# Facebook malayalam(regional font) in chrome looks way too small to read

Tags: google-chrome, fonts, facebook

Cannot see malayalam font in equal size as that of English in Facebook.com in chrome for Ubuntu. Also some letters appear big and all others too small. I would also want to increase the font colour to pure black so that there is much more contrast.

Comment: did you try using malyalam font in chrome in windows?
How does it look?

Answer (score 2):

Try this

```
sudo apt-add-repository ppa:smcproject/repo
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get remove ttf-freefont ttf-indic-fonts-core ttf-malayalam-fonts
sudo apt-get install fonts-smc
```

Reference: https://ml.wikipedia.org/wiki/%E0%B4%B8%E0%B4%B9%E0%B4%BE%E0%B4%AF%E0%B4%82:To_Read_in_Malayalam

Comment: Yes that answers the question. I can see my fonts now, however, if you see 2 lines with English and Malayalam, the height and size of the malayalam font is so small when compared to English. Additionally due to the lack of contrast in the font of Ubuntu, it is real pain to the eyes. Thanks anyway. Is there any fix for the same?

Comment: I too face this issue, anybody?

Comment: I couldn't find a solution for the smaller sizes